# Why won't my dataGridView refresh?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using Windows Forms and have a data set that I populated with a list of the data I wanted.

```
DataSet ds = ToDataSet(customers);
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0].Clone();

dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
 if (dataGridView1.DataSource == null)
     dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
 dataGridView1.EndEdit();
 dataGridView1.Refresh();
 dataGridView1.Parent.Refresh();
```

I've tried the above. I've tried setting DataSource to just the first table (dt). I've tried setting DataMember to the Table name. I've tried using a BindingList instead.  Nothing is helping.

Any ideas why this won't work?

Comment: is there any `Column` rendered? if there are some columns but no rows, it may be that your DataSource is empty.

Comment: What means "refresh", do you wonder why the `dataGridView` shows no data? Btw, `Clone` just creates a table with the same schema, the data is not copied, so it remains empty.

Comment: Tim's comment seems to be the problem.

Comment: I've looked at the dataset while debugging and it definitely does have the information in it.